# Execute permissions set but still getting 'No such file or directory'

Tags: linux, permissions, binary-files

I'm trying to run a binary file from bash but I get the above error when I try `./launcher` from the directory it's located. Execute permissions and owner are all in order so what's the issue?

Comment: did you do  `chmod +X ` on the file you trying to execute ?

Comment: What steps did you take to set it up...?  Does it allow you to run `sh  launcher`?